Classifying Table Headers from Column Data
I have a large set CSVs with numeric and text data; here's a sample:



Company ID
Company Name
Group ID
Currency
Amount
...




8494494
Acme Inc
F942G
EUR
$1.56
...


9283422A
Walmart
XXH3F3
AUD
$5.64
...


...
...
...
...
...
...



I have a separate set of CSVs for which the headers may be mislabeled. I'd like to build classifiers to determine whether the columns in this other set are Company ID, Company Name, or Group ID.
The data in these 3 columns are complex enough that I cannot solve this with regexp alone; however, from an eye-test, I believe a simple classifier can be trained to distinguish between them (and also return False for other miscellaneous data such as "AUD").
What model is best to use here? I've considered passing these strings through BERT and then building a classifier on top of the embeddings. I've also considered just training a RNN at the character level.
~
PS: Two more ideas I had that are a bit more complex:

Would passing these strings through a NER model be appropriate? Or would that be overkill since there is not much 'sequential' information here?
Another idea is to take a "word2vec" approach and try to create my own custom embeddings, but use my training data to 'push' the embeddings far from each other for the different columns.


To be sure I understand you correctly, you are planning on classifying based on the contents of your csv and not on the headers? What types of mistakes do you see in the headers, is it misspelled or just the order that is messed up? And also, how standard are your column characteristics? If it's very similar, you could classify in a simpler way such as n-grams with naive bayes or logistic regression, but that is a relevant thing to know.

That's correct- for example, I would run each cell through the "Company ID classifier model" to get a classification score in [0,1], and then I would look for columns where all values are high. The headers in the second set have misspellings, or they can be worded differently (e.g. just "Company" for "Company ID"). The column characteristics are quite similar within columns. Of course, "Company Name" is most different from the other two. But the two "ID" columns may be different in more subtle ways (but still distinguishable)

@olives, are you seeking an opinion or solution approach? The classification model based on BERT or Roberta is your best shot since you have enough sample data to train to.

Before trying your suggested methods, I would take a more simple approach than the ones suggested, for example have a look at n-grams. Then train a simple classifier, for example the logistic regression or a naive Bayes classifier like this post.
I think that should work for most columns that you have here, possibly only the ID columns such as Group ID and Company ID might get difficult as there are no clear patterns in what they look like. Maybe have a look on how you would distinguish such column and whether they are too random for this approach.
This would probably be easier than going towards embeddings, I think it should be quite effective.

I like this idea, but Company ID and Group ID are exactly 2 out of the 3 columns I am trying to predict. The set (Company ID, Company Name, Group ID) are exactly the 3 I want, they were not examples.

What do you use to recognize whether it's Company ID or Group ID in your eye-test? As you mention that you are able to distinguish them. Might help in finding a solution.

In my eye test I see some attributes like length (Company IDs are typically 8-10 alphanumeric characters long, while Group IDs are 5-7), regexp (eg mixture of letters and numbers for IDs, versus only letters for Names). I could draft up 10-20 of these features (string_length, contains_regexp_{REGEXP}) and use this to build a classifier, but I guess I was wondering if using a RNN or embeddings would be more performant.

Actually, here's a different idea that's also quite simple: what if for the identifier classification models, I use 2 HMMs, one at the alphanumeric character level, and one at the length level? For Name classification, I could use BOW + Naive Bayes
